# Función recursiva infinita que cuando finalice lea los valores originales

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo una función recursiva que muestra el contenido de un array de manera infinita. Cada vez que se muestra un item, lo elimino así de manera sucesiva, cuando el array está vació necesito volver a leer los valores del array original(**mascotas**).

Funciona cuando pongo los valores manualmente(**['perro', 'gato', 'hamster']**), pero no cuando llamo al array original(**mascotas**). Esto es lo que necesito porque serán arrays muy grandes.

```js
const mascotas = ['perro', 'gato', 'hamster']

const mostrarMascotas = (mc) => {
    let actual = mc

    setTimeout(() => {
        if ( actual.length >= 2 ) mostrarMascotas(actual)
        if ( actual.length == 1 ) mostrarMascotas(['perro', 'gato', 'hamster'])

        console.log(actual)
        actual.shift()
    }, 1000)
}

mostrarMascotas(mascotas)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! antes de meterme en porque no ves el array original (un problema de scope), si es una funcion recursiva eterna, va a tirar StackOverflow... no puede ser recursiva eternamente....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te funciona porque estás modificando el array original, sencillamente cuando inicies el ciclo o cuando quieras reiniciarlo, pasa una copia del array, no el array original, usando `[...mascotas]`.

```js
const mascotas = ['perro', 'gato', 'hamster']

const mostrarMascotas = (mc) => {
    let actual = mc

    setTimeout(() => {
        if ( actual.length >= 2 ) mostrarMascotas(actual)
        if ( actual.length == 1 ) mostrarMascotas([...mascotas])

        console.log(actual)
        actual.shift()
    }, 1000)
}

mostrarMascotas([...mascotas])
```

Comment: "Esto es lo que necesito porque serán arrays muy grandes".. yo le recalcaria lo que puse en mi comentario.. si es una funcion recursiva, la posibilidad de un SO es enorme....

Comment: Claramente no es una función recursiva (pero casi) es una función que se llama a si misma después de un tiempo, eso no causa que se llene el stack, solo se programa para que se ejecute de nuevo mas adelante. Si no estuviera el setTimeout estaría de acuerdo que es recursiva y podría causar stack overflow.

Comment: @Pipe buenisimo.. gran aclaracion...